# Using Observable/Observer with two different double variables?

Tags: java, observable

I have a class that monitors the stock market. It holds 2 values (doubles) the daily high and the daily low. I want to monitor these variables from another class and take action if either changes. (i.e. change a limit order)

So, I have a `class LiveOrderBook extends Observable` and two methods inside that update the price:

```
public void setDailyLow(double price){
    low = price;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers(low);
}

public void setDailyHigh(double price){
    high = price;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers(high);
}
```

I need to observe these price variables so I made a `class PriceObserver  implements Observer`. My plan is to create PriceObserver objects inside my `Bid` class that changes stock market bids.

My PriceObserver class

```
private double low;
private double high;

public PriceObserver(){

    low = 0;
    high = 0;
}

public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

How do I now specify which `double` should be updated? I can't check if arg0 == the variable name from the other class, so how is this done?

Comment: *low* and *high* are different events and therefore you should create different *observers*. Also: when dealing with money using `float` or `double` will cause problems because of the *fixed lengh nuber aproximation* i.e.: decimal value `0.1` cannot be exaclty represented in binary since it is an *endless fraction*.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle ok, so you're saying I need two classes, LowPriceObserver and HighPriceObserver that both implement Observer. This is going to be a dumb question, but how do you differentiate between setChanged(); notifyObservers(high); for LowPriceObserver vs the HighPriceObserver?

Comment: Obvoiusly you also need to ahndle two lists of observers, one vor each event.

Answer (score 3):

An easy (and useful) approach is to first create different event classes that can get dispatched:

```
public class LowPriceChangedEvent {
    private double price;
    // Constructor and getter up to you.
}

public class HighPriceChangedEvent {
    private double price;
    // Constructor and getter up to you.
}
```

Now you can dispatch these events in your `LiveOrderBook` class:

```
public void setDailyLow(double price){
    low = price;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers(new LowPriceChangedEvent(low));
}

public void setDailyHigh(double price){
    high = price;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers(new HighPriceChangedEvent(low));
}
```

Your `PriceObserver` now easily can distinguish the events by doing a simple `instanceOf` check:

```
public class PriceObserver implements Observer {
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        if (arg instanceOf LowPriceChangedEvent) {
            ...
        } else  if (arg instanceOf HighPriceChangedEvent) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, this makes sense. But if I construct the new LowPriceChangedEvent and HighPriceChangedEvent on the fly inside notifyObservers, how can I reference them inside my "Bid" class where I actually need to monitor the change in prices?

Comment: I think my confusion is rooted in the fact that I thought LowPriceChangedEvent and HighPriceChangedEvent were taking the place of the PriceObserver class.

Answer (score 0):

Your **arg1** is an Object. I would suggest calling your notifyObservers method with a double[] (all arrays are castable to Object).

i.e.

```
notifyObservers(new double[] {low, high});
```